# Draw lines on the camera and save the cropped image in Android

Tags: android, image, camera

I have to make an application where you need to take pictures. I followed the tutorial to create a google camerapreview (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html # custom-camera). I did everything that's there and tried to create the rectangle I need, but does not work, neither on the emulator or on my cell (S3 mini - android 4.1.2)

The image gives an idea of what I need.

[image]

I need a rectangle on the camera where the user align the signal (of the photo), on this red rectangle, then takes the photo and automatically saving of the image that is inside the red rectangle. Please, if anyone has done something like give me a light.

thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you first take the picture, and let the user crop it afterwards. The reason is that capture may take significant time, and also the captured image geometry may be different from the preview.

Comment: That make sense. I will try this. Do you have some example of this?

Comment: Just so you know there are plenty of image cropping libraries, just Google it. One I found is here https://github.com/edmodo/cropper (Not mine)